# Javascript difference between loop "FOR"

Tags: javascript, dom

HTML :

```
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</body>
```

Javascript :

```
window.onload = function() {
  var canvasElements = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
  for ( var index in canvasElements) {
  }
  for ( var index = 0; index < canvasElements.length; index++) {
  }
}
```

These two loop does not have same iteration number. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")` returns an HTMLCollection that have one propertie, "length" and two methods, "item" and "namedItem".

So the FOR ... IN loop iterate over items in that collection and over the members of the HTMLCollection.
So There is 5 iterations:

- 2 iterations for each HTMLElement, here canvasElement
- 2 iterations for eahc methods : item, namedItem
- 1 iteration for the propertie : length

The for(...;...;...) loop only iterate over items because document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[index] refere to an item

Hope this response was clear !
Ask for more information otherwise...

Some references :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLElement
- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#htmlelement
- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-58190037
- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506